# Issue getting the right property value in a multithread environment

Tags: ios, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch

I am trying to offload some heavy work during the initialization of an object. I have added a status property that i set when i have fully initialized all other instances variables of my object. I have simplify my whole approach through the following example:

This is my class (Foo) that has my initializer:

// - header file

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

typedef void (^loadingCompletionBlock)(BOOL success);

typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, FooStatus) {
    FooCreated,
    FooReady,
    FooFailed,
};


@interface Foo : NSObject

+ (id) withCompletionBlock:(loadingCompletionBlock) block;

@property (assign, nonatomic) FooStatus status;

@end
```

// - implementation file

```
@implementation Foo

- (FooStatus) status {

    __block FooStatus readStatus;

    dispatch_sync([Foo concurrentLoadingQueue], ^{
        readStatus = _status;
    });

    return readStatus;
}

+ (dispatch_queue_t)concurrentLoadingQueue
{
    static dispatch_queue_t sharedQueue;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;

    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedQueue = dispatch_queue_create("test.loadingQueue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT);
    });

    return sharedQueue;
}


+ (id)withCompletionBlock:(loadingCompletionBlock) completed {

    Foo* foo = [[Foo alloc] init];
    foo.status = FooCreated;

    dispatch_async([Foo concurrentLoadingQueue], ^{

        for (int i=0; i<10000; i++)
        {
            NSLog(@"Running long tasks: %d", i);
        }

        foo.status = FooReady;

        completed(YES);

        NSLog(@"Foo status: %d (Background Thread)", foo.status);

    });


    return foo;

};

@end
```

I am invoking then the following code on the main thread:

```
 Foo* foo = [Foo withCompletionBlock:^(BOOL success) {

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

             NSLog(@"Foo status: %d (Main Thread)", foo.status);

        });
    }];

    NSLog(@"Foo status: %d (Main Thread)", foo.status);
```

The NSLog will give me those outputs:

```
2014-10-01 07:09:49.606 TestConcurrentQueue[15610:60b] Foo status: 0 (Main Thread)
2014-10-01 07:09:52.818 TestConcurrentQueue[15610:1303] Running long tasks: 1
2014-10-01 07:09:52.818 TestConcurrentQueue[15610:1303] ......
2014-10-01 07:09:52.818 TestConcurrentQueue[15610:1303] Running long tasks: 9999
2014-10-01 07:09:52.818 TestConcurrentQueue[15610:60b] Foo status: 0 (Main Thread)
2014-10-01 07:09:52.818 TestConcurrentQueue[15610:1303] Foo status: 1 (Background Thread)
```

The 0 being status created and 1 ready why i can't get the right value within my main thread?

Comment: Inside the completion block where you log `foo.status` on the main thread, is `foo` actually set? See if `foo` is `nil`.

Comment: If you are going to access a property from multiple threads like that you should declare it as `atomic` not `nonatomic`.  Also, a dispatch group could be a better approach https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH102-SW25

Comment: Just for laughs, declare the backing store variable `_status` and make it a `volatile BOOL` and see if that helps.

Comment: @rmaddy yes foo is not set: it is nil

Comment: @Paulw11 isn't the dispatchsync i am doin when reading the status menber variable supposed to do the job? I have considered using a dispatch_group but i want to get notify each time a task has completed instead of all the task being completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe `foo` is `nil` inside the completion block because `foo` is being created and assigned as a result of the original method call.

A simple solution would be to pass the created object as a parameter to the completion block, along with the `BOOL`.

A better approach might be to make your `withCompletionBlock:` an instance method instead of a class method. Then your calling code would be something like:

```
Foo* foo = [[Foo alloc] init];
[foo populateWithCompletionBlock:^(BOOL success) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
         NSLog(@"Foo status: %d (Main Thread)", foo.status);
    });
}];

NSLog(@"Foo status: %d (Main Thread)", foo.status);
```

This way the `foo` inside the completion block is referencing an object that actually exists.

The `init` method of `Foo` would set the initial status and that's all.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you have any feedbacks btw regarding the way i have defined my getter for the status property? Is it correct or i should consider declaring my property with the atomic keyword. I still have some uncertainty here.

Comment: Any property that you know will be accessed from multiple threads should be `atomic`. If you know for sure only one thread can ever access a property of a given instance, than `nonatomic` is good.

Comment: I see so it should be good in the scenario i have illustrated: thanks for the clarification.